# Tensorflow [Toco] convert Model to optimized format cause ValueError

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, toco

I just started trying Tensorflow, I'd like to do some experiments on Android, but I read that Tensorflow for Poets (the version for mobile) support .tflite while the models I downloaded and found googling are .pb.

So I decided to convert them using toco, but when I execute the command to convert I always get this error

> ValueError: Invalid tensors 'input' were found.

The CLI command is:

```
toco   --graph_def_file=tensorflow_inception_graph.pb   --output_file=optimized_graph.tflite   --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF --output_format=TFLITE   --input_shape=1,300,300,3   --input_array=input   --o
utput_array=final_result   --inference_type=FLOAT   --inference_input_type=FLOAT
```

What's wrong with that?

**Stacktrace**

```
File "/home/Mitro/venv/bin/toco", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/Mitro/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 401, in main
    app.run(main=run_main, argv=sys.argv[:1])
  File "/home/Mitro/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/home/Mitro/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 397, in run_main
    _convert_model(tflite_flags)
  File "/home/Mitro/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 100, in _convert_model
    converter = _get_toco_converter(flags)
  File "/home/Mitro/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 87, in _get_toco_converter
    return converter_fn(**converter_kwargs)
  File "/home/Mitro/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/lite.py", line 271, in from_frozen_graph
    sess.graph, input_arrays)
  File "/home/Mitro/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/convert_saved_model.py", line 189, in get_tensors_from_tensor_names
    ",".join(invalid_tensors)))
```

[My reference from Google](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2-tflite/#2)

Comment: What TF version are you using? Was everything compiled with Python3?

Comment: Version 1.11, compied with python 3.5

Comment: Hmm okay. So, waht I would do now is to look at the tensor_names and check which one throws throws this error. You could also check [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tf_ops_compatibility#compatible_operations) if your used tensor operations are compatible with TF Lite

Answer (score 0):

Run this [script](https://github.com/rdeepc/Tensorflow_lite_tutorial/blob/master/modelinfo.py) changing the model_file parameter to the pb file, and as an output you will have something like this:

Tensor("import/**Placeholder**:0", shape=(?, 299, 299, 3), dtype=float32)
Tensor("import/**final_result**:0", shape=(?, 5), dtype=float32)

in this case they are the parameters that you must pass through
--input_array = **Placeholder**
--output_array = **final_result**

[Here](https://medium.com/@rdeep/tensorflow-lite-tutorial-easy-implementation-in-android-145443ec3775) is the complete information